# Formatting a 2D list of floats to 2 decimal points; Python

Tags: python, list, formatting

First off, I know a similar question has been asked before but I think the situation called for a different method of approach than mine does.

I have a list of temperatures that I just need to print out with 2 decimals. So far I have:

```
def getWeekAverages():
    weekAverages = []
    MAX = WEEKS
    total = 0
    for week in range (WEEKS):
        total = 0        
        for day in range(len(DAYS)):
            total += round(float(database[week][day]), 2)

        weekAverages.append(total/7)

    return weekAverages
```

I've tried about 10 different ways to do this, including sing "%.2f" and round. I am not very familiar with numpy arrays so I may just have to read more into that. When i run the program nothing has changed and my output comes to:

```
The average temperatures for a given week are   [77.71428571428571, 71.71428571428571, 74.0, 77.85714285714286, 35.42857142857143, 0.0]
```

I appreciate anyone's time they provide.

Comment: Use `float` instead of `int`.

Comment: you mean where i augment total? i tried and i still gives me the same error

Comment: That's the only place in the code you posted where you call the `int()` function. Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with a _full_ traceback.

Comment: There error does not seem to be related to formatting at all please make sure to update your post with more reasonable title.

Comment: What is `database`?  If it is something with fixed (integer) type, like a numpy array with `dtype=numpy.int`, then that could give you the error you see on the line you indicate.

Comment: got it im sorry about that. my program is under 200 lines would it be more better for you ll if i recreated a program or if you gave me a general example of formatting a list?

Comment: database is just an empty list used to store the numbers from a .txt document

Comment: `weekAverages.append(float(total/7.0),2)`?

Answer (score 3):

You are using `int()` to parse a string representation of a floating-point number. You should do that with `float()`.

```
total += float(database[week][day])
```

If you want to turn that into an integer, you can either round it (Python 3's `round()` returns an `int` when rounding to zero decimal places) or use the `int()` function on that `float` (it can't handle *strings* that represent floating-point numbers, but it can find the floor of a floating-point number).

```
total = int(total)
```

Comment: This would indeed give the same `ValueError`, but the question says the error occurs on the preceding line.

Comment: the problem I'm realizing is that I have a 2D array and i have only seens ways to format a single dimension array